# Writing an array to csv file and getting extra lines

Tags: python

Learning Python and writing a little quiz program. I built a set of questions in Excel and exported them to a CSV fle. Then I read the csv in my Python program and load an array. See code below:

```py
matrix = [[0 for x in range(w)] for y in range(h)]
with open(quizfile,'r') as csvfile:
    datacsv = csv.reader(csvfile)
    matrix = list(datacsv)
```

That works fine and I can work with the array just fine. I update some of the array values and attempt to write the csv file back using:

```py
with open(quizfile,'w') as csvfile:
    csvWriter = csv.writer(csvfile,delimiter=',')
    csvWriter.writerows(matrix)
```

The file I read looks like this:

> 100,What is your name,Doug 
> 100,What is your quest,To seek the holy grail 
> 100,What is the airspeed velocity of an unladen swallow,African or European

I adjust the values in the first column from 100 to 80, and what I write looks like this:

> 80,What is your name,Doug
>
> 80,What is your quest,To seek the holy grail
>
> 80,What is the airspeed velocity of an unladen swallow,African or European

Notice the blank line between each data line. When I read this updated file back in my code chokes with an index out of range on the second array row.

Comment: Variable and function names should generally follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`csv.writer` sometimes adds an extra `\r` unless you open with `newline=''`:

> If `newline=''` is not specified, newlines embedded inside quoted fields will not be interpreted correctly, and on platforms that use `\r\n` linendings on write an extra `\r` will be added. It should always be safe to specify `newline=''`, since the csv module does its own (universal) newline handling.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#id3

This should fix it:

```
with open(quizfile,'w',newline='') as csvfile:
    csvWriter = csv.writer(csvfile,delimiter=',')
    csvWriter.writerows(matrix)
```

Answer (score 1):

Update `newline=''` as below

```
with open(quizfile,'w', newline='') as csvfile:
```